# How can i check if all the files were downloaded?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Before i tried to check if progressBar2 that show overall download progress is at 100% but it's not really working. Is there another way more sure way to check it ?

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //urll.Add("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip");
            btnDownload.Enabled = false;
            label7.Text = "Downloading...";
            getTotalBytes(countryList);
            CreateCountryDateTimeDirectories(newList);
            downloadFile(newList);
        }

        private Queue<string> _downloadUrls = new Queue<string>();

        private async void downloadFile(IEnumerable<string> urls)
        {
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
            }

            await DownloadFile();
        }

        private async Task DownloadFile()
        {
            if (_downloadUrls.Any())
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += Completed;

                var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();

                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                if (url.Contains("true"))
                {
                    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), countriesMainPath + "\\" + currentDownloadCountry + "\\" + count + "Infrared.jpg");
                }
                else
                {
                    await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(url), countriesMainPath + "\\" + currentDownloadCountry + "\\" + count + "Invisible.jpg");
                }

                return;
            }
        }

        double percentageTotalDownload = 0;
        double totalBytesDownloaded = 0;
        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Calculate download speed and output it to labelSpeed.
            label3.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));

            // Update the progressbar percentage only when the value is not the same.
            double bytesInCurrentDownload = (double)e.BytesReceived;
            double totalBytesCurrentDownload = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentageCurrentDownload = bytesInCurrentDownload / totalBytesCurrentDownload * 100;
            ProgressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentageCurrentDownload).ToString());//e.ProgressPercentage;
                                                                                                // Show the percentage on our label.
            Label4.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

            // Update the label with how much data have been downloaded so far and the total size of the file we are currently downloading
            label10.Text = string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's",
                (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
                (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));

            //Let's update ProgressBar2
            totalBytesDownloaded = e.BytesReceived + bytesFromCompletedFiles;
            percentageTotalDownload = totalBytesDownloaded / totalBytesToDownload * 100;
            progressBar2.Value = (int)percentageTotalDownload;
            label6.Text = progressBar2.Value.ToString() + "%";
        }

        long bytesFromCompletedFiles = 0;
        // The event that will trigger when the WebClient is completed
        private async void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          await DownloadFile();
        }
```

For example if i have 100 urls and it's start downloading then i want to know in the completed event when all the files downloaded and not only one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of how many downloads have been completed in an counter variable. Because of the multiple threads that can access that counter, use the [`Interlocked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) class to manipulate that counter.

This are the changes needed in your code:

```
private int urlCount = 0; // keep track of how many urls are processed

private async void downloadFile(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    urlCount = 0;
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
        urlCount++;
    }
    // urlCount is now set
    await DownloadFile();
}
```

And here is the handling of the counter and the check if we are done

```
private async void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // urlCount will be decremented
    // cnt will get its value
    var cnt = System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref urlCount);

    if (cnt > 0) {
        await DownloadFile();
    } 
    else
    {
        // call here what ever you want to happen when everything is 
        // downloaded
        "Done".Dump();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't understood it very well, but what you are trying to accomplish is that your progress bar is showing progress of download all files and not one file then reset then another file that reset.

If that is the case, then why you do not try foreach file get size and sum it to   `totalBytesToDownload` and then use it in progress bar

So

```
foreach(string url in urll)
{
    //get url file size
    totalBytesToDownload = totalBytesToDownload + urlSizeYouGot;
}
```